# How to get the first name of a Firebase user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a user who is authenticated via Firebase Auth. I can get their display name but was wondering how to get their first name only. Do  I have to use some sort of Token to call the FB Graph API?

Sincerely
Vishaal

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, you need to get a Token which basically allows you to get the Facebook details of an user.

Once you get a validated token, then you can use FB Graph API to extract the basic information.

Here is a sample code.

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error
                {
                    print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(okayAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    return
                }
            if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {
                var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:["fields":"first_name,last_name,email"],  httpMethod: "GET")
                request?.start(completionHandler: {(connection,result,error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil)
                {
                    var dictionary_user_info = result as? NSDictionary
                    let v_firstname = dictionary_user_info?.object(forKey: "first_name") as! String
                    let v_lastname = dictionary_user_info?.object(forKey: "last_name") as! String
                    let v_email = dictionary_user_info?.object(forKey: "email") as! String
                    }
                  }
                }
```